# boost::gregorian::date with time?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

So far it looks like `boost::gregorian::date` only has day/month/year. I need to also store hour/minute/second. Can this object handle both? I'm having difficulty understanding how to represent all of this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this object cannot handle that (because then `boost::gregorian::date` wouldn't be a ... `date`).

If you need a datetime, use `boost::posix_time::ptime` (which is a tuple of `gregorian::date, time_duration`).

If you *also* need a timezone look at [`boost::local_time::local_date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.local_date_time) or Boost Locale's [date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1date__time.html)

Comment: Thanks; I do find the objects to be rather confusing, so this helps.